# call bash function with argument and pass result through grep

Tags: bash

From a bash script, I would like to test if a virtualenv (`dev`) exists by

```
lsvirtualenv -b | grep dev
```

`lsvirtualenv` is implemented as a bash function (the `-b` gives a short listing with just the known virtualenv names, each on a separate line).

I've tried

```
if [[ $(lsvirtualenv -b | grep ${VENV_NAME}) ]]; then
    echo "HAVE ${VENV_NAME}"
else
    echo "VENV ${VENV_NAME} missing"
fi
```

but that gives me

```
lsvirtualenv: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `grep` creates a useful return code, the use of `[[...]]` is not necessary.  Try:

```
. /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh
if lsvirtualenv -b | grep -q "${VENV_NAME}"
then
    echo "HAVE ${VENV_NAME}"
else
    echo "VENV ${VENV_NAME} missing"
fi
```

Two comments:

1. The shell's `if` statement uses the exit code of the command which follows the `if`.  The test commands, like `[[...]]` and `[...]`, can be used to set an exit code.  But, `if` does not need them.  Any command which sets an exit code can be used.  In this case, `grep` sets the exit code based on whether or not the string was found.
2. The `-q` option to `grep` silences it.  With this option, `grep` sets an exit code but does not produce any other output.
3. Here, `lsvirtualenv` runs in the script's shell, not a subshell. So, as long as it is available to your script, it will work here, no export necessary.

Comment: It seems `lsvirtualenv` isn't available to my shell (I'm getting "lsvirtualenv: command not found")

Comment: @thebjorn You likely need to run source the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script.  See the new line in the updated answer.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, now that I think about it.. (that worked btw., thanks!)